# Multiple LookupField?

Tags: 2010, list, lookup-column

I have a couple of problems that i would need help with.

I need to create a list that has a lookup to multiple lists. Is there a way to do this without including third party.

I have a site, with a list inside the site that has lets say sells reports. I then have multiple of sites with the same try of list. After that i have an administrator that looks at all those sub site's sell reports. The problem is now i need to be able to make a column in another list that points to possible one of any of those sells report.

HELP :'(

ps: temporarly merging multiple list in code would also fix this, anyone ?

Comment: You mean to say you want to create a LookUp type column which reference to a list from Another Site..??

Comment: No exactly, reference multiple list that contain the same content column across multiple sub site of the intranet.

Comment: As what you are asking is not possible in SharePoint Out of The Box. For that you have to do some custom coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, SharePoint doesn't support lookup columns from a different sites.  This is primarily for security reasons.

You would need third-party tools or custom development work to make this happen.

If you have the same static data you would like to reference from lists in multiple sites, you could create the first list with the data you want.  Then in the List Settings, save it as a template.  Then you will be able to re-create that list in any site with the data.